# What is the difference between .net data providers and odbc drivers?

Tags: asp.net, .net, odbc

Can you please help me understand the difference between these two technologies of connecting to databases?

I am new to the field of database connectivity, but may you can explain on specific examples which technology is used in each case? What for example should I use if I am developing the application ob Visual Studio and going to connect in with MySQL and why?

May be the question will seem stupid for the professionals, but I would be very thankful if you will clarify it for me.

Answer (score 1):

A .NET data provider is a software component that provides access to a data source. They specifically designed to work in .NET applications (C#, VB.NET, etc.) and will have at least some standard classes/functions: Connection, Command, DataReader, DataAdapter (similar to the native System.Data.SQLClient classes).

An ODBC driver is very similar, but is written using the ODBC standard, and while it can be used programmatically in applications, it is also capable of being used as a data connector in any number of popular BI/reporting/ETL tools (like Tableau, QlikView, PowerBI, etc.). To use an ODBC driver in a .NET application, you'll need to use the [Microsoft.Data.ODBC library](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310988).

For your use case, you'll want to use an ADO.NET data provider so that you can be sure that you're using a product that was specifically designed to be used in .NET applications. Some basic code would look similar to the following:

```
string connString = "server=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;database=myDatabase;user=myUser;password=myPassword;...";

using (MySQLConnection conn = new MySQLConnection(connString){

  MySQLCommand cmd = new MySQLCommand("SELECT * FROM some_table", conn);
  MySQLDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

  while(rdr.Read()) {

    Console.WriteLine("=================");

    for (int i=0; i<rdr.FieldCount; i++) {
      Console.WriteLine(rdr.GetName(i) + ":\t\t" + rdr.GetValue(i));
    }
  }
}
```